# CSS overriding for different pages in Single page application

Tags: css, angularjs, less, webpack, single-page-application

I am building SPA with `angular.js`, two pages, login and dashboard has different background, but since it's a single page application after login the background color doesn't change to the new color mentioned in `dashboard.less` file. In this case I use `!important`, dashboard background get reflected even after logout.

I want specific page css only to be loaded on ui-routing.

Kindly suggest a fix for it. I am using less with webpack. I know such issues will come for later pages too. How can I avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have a solution here
https://github.com/manuelmazzuola/angular-ui-router-styles

Add this framwork
and use it like

```
 .state('state1', {
    url: '/state1',
    controller: 'State1controller',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    data: {
      css: [
        'styles/custom-state1.css',
        {
          name: 'layout',
          href: 'styles/state1-layout.css'
        }
      ]
    }
  })
```

Comment: have tried this, only problem is we are using less with webpack and dont have access to .css file thats getting processed when its running in the browser. any help there?

Comment: : can u tell me an option on how i can get this css file thats been compiled by webpack ?  so i can pass them individually to different router

Answer (score 0):

well you could do something like this.

```
<link data-ng-if="page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-ng-href="css/app/page/{{page.css}}/page.css" />
```

where when you do a ui-routing and load the controller.

you would have

```
$scope.page = {css: "loginpage"};
```